# Why does this error occur when using Trino to connect to Phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix, dbeaver, trino

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq2Vc.png)

I used dbeaver to connect to Trino of Phoenix, and there was such an error
 `Could not load/instantiate class org.apache.phoenix.query.DefaultGuidePostsCacheFactory`
this my configuration

1. hbase version 2.3.4
2. phoenix version 5.1
3. trino version 353
4. phoenix5 jar  phoenix-client-embedded-hbase-2.3-5.1.0.jar

Comment: What's your catalog configuration properties file?

Comment: <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec</value>
  </property>

    <property>
        <name>phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>phoenix.schema.mapSystemTablesToNamespace</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

</configuration>